# How to escape echo?

Tags: bash

***Edit:*** I realized that this has nothing to do with `$()` it's just the result of using `echo *`. So I just need a way to escape with `echo`.

I'm writing a script that checks what users don't have passwords by comparing `/etc/passwd` and `/etc/shadow`.

So far I have:

```
cat /etc/passwd | while read -r line ; do
  user=$(echo $line | cut -d ":" -f 1)
  password=$(cat /etc/shadow | grep $user | cut -d ":" -f 2)
  echo $password
done
```

The problem is that when the result of my grep is `*` for the password field, which is the case for all users without a password, it seems like `ls *` is performed? For example:

[image]

<s>I'm confused as to why this is happening. Can anyone explain what is happening here?</s> The one answer at the bottom of the picture with an encrypted password is the expected behavior. For the entries without a password I was expecting to get back a `*`.

Comment: You need to quote your variables; e.g., `echo "$password"`. I suspect we already have an answer that covers this in detail; going to try to find it.

Comment: FYI you may find that your system's `passwd` command has a `-S` (`--status`) option that can do exactly this task for you

Comment: @steeldriver when I run `passwd --status` I get back `philip P 04/14/2017 0 99999 7 -1`. Seems it only runs for the user who uses the command, where as I need to look at all users on the system.

Comment: Superuser should be able to add `-a` to see the status of all accounts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
echo "$password"
```

This will allow interpolation of the variable (here, into `*`) without invoking shell globing.